# How to replace multiple commas in a string column with single comma in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe

```
val df = Seq(
(",,,,104,,,,,,,111,,,114,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,131,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,157,,,,,162,,,,,,,169,,,,,174,,176,,,,,,,,,,,,,                                    "),
(",,,,104,,,,,,,111,,,114,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,131,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,157,,,,,162,,,,,,,169,,,,,174,,176,,,,,,,,,,,,,                                    "),
(",,,,104,,,,,,,111,,,114,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,131,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,157,,,,,162,,,,,,,169,,,,,174,,176,,,,,,,,,,,,,                                    "),
(",,,,104,,,,,,,111,,,114,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,131,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,157,,,160,,162,,,,,,,,,,,,174,,176,,,,,,,,,,,,,                                    "),
(",,,,104,,,,,,,111,,,114,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,131,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,157,,,,,162,,,,,,,169,,,,,174,,176,,,,,,,,,,,,,                                    "),
(",,,,104,,,,,,,111,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,131,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,157,,,160,,162,,,,,,,169,,,,,174,,176,,,,,,,,,,,,,                                    "),
(",,,103,104,,,,,,,111,,,114,,,,,,,121,,,,,,,,,,131,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,157,,,,,162,,,,,,,169,,,,,174,,176,,,,,,,,,,,,,                              "),
(",101,102,,104,,,,,,,,,113,114,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,130,131,,,,,,,,,,141,142,143,,,146,,,,150,,152,,,,,157,,,,,162,,,,,,,,,,,,174,,,,,,,,,,184,,,,,            "),
(",,,,104,,,,,,,,,113,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,131,,,,,,,,,,141,142,143,,,146,,,,150,,,,,155,,157,,,,,162,,,,,,,169,,,,,174,,176,177,178,,,,,,,,,,,               "),
(",,,,104,,,,,,,111,,,114,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,131,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,157,,,,,162,,,,,,,,,,,,174,,176,,,,,,,,,,,,,                                       "),
(",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,                                                               "),
(",,102,,104,,,,,,,,,113,114,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,130,131,,,,,,,,,,141,142,143,,,146,,,,150,,152,,,,,157,,,,,162,,,,,,,,,,,,174,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,                  "),
(",,,,104,,,,,,,111,112,,114,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,131,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,157,,,,,162,,,,,,,169,,,,,174,,176,,,,,,,,,,,,,                                 "),
(",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,                                                               "),
(",,102,103,104,,,,,,,,,113,114,,,,,,,121,,,,,,,,,130,131,,,,,,,,,,141,142,143,,,146,,,,150,,152,,,,,157,,,160,,162,,,,,,,,,,,173,174,,176,,178,,,,,,,,,,,"),
(",,,,104,,,,,,,111,,,114,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,131,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,157,,,,,162,,,,,,,,,,,,174,,176,,,,,,,,,,,,,                                       "),
(",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,                                                               "),
(",,,103,104,,,,,,,111,,,114,,,,,,,121,,,,,,,,,,131,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,157,,,,,162,,,,,,,169,,,,,174,,176,,,,,,,,,,,,,                              "),
(",,,,104,,,,,,,111,,,114,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,131,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,157,,,,,162,,,,,,,169,,,,,174,,176,,,,,,,,,,,,,                                    "),
(",,102,,104,,,,,,,,,113,114,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,130,131,,,,,,,,,,141,142,143,,,146,,,,150,,152,,,,,157,,,,,162,,,,,,,,,,,,174,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,                  ")
).toDF("my_col")
```

I want to remove unecessary commas from this column. So for instance the first record should appear as `104,111,114,131,157,162,169,174,176` in the output.

It is not necessary for the string to start and end with a comma.

How do I do this in Spark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, split the string with delim ",". Then use array_remove function to remove empty string. Join the array back to string. There is a trailing ",". To remove that a udf to drop the rightmost char in the string.

```
scala> df.show(false)
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|my_col                                                                                                                                                  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|,,,,104,,,,,,,111,,,114,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,131,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,157,,,,,162,,,,,,,169,,,,,174,,176,,,,,,,,,,,,,                                    |
|,,,,104,,,,,,,111,,,114,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,131,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,157,,,,,162,,,,,,,169,,,,,174,,176,,,,,,,,,,,,,                                    |
|,,,,104,,,,,,,111,,,114,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,131,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,157,,,,,162,,,,,,,169,,,,,174,,176,,,,,,,,,,,,,                                    |
|,,,,104,,,,,,,111,,,114,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,131,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,157,,,160,,162,,,,,,,,,,,,174,,176,,,,,,,,,,,,,                                    |
|,,,,104,,,,,,,111,,,114,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,131,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,157,,,,,162,,,,,,,169,,,,,174,,176,,,,,,,,,,,,,                                    |
|,,,,104,,,,,,,111,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,131,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,157,,,160,,162,,,,,,,169,,,,,174,,176,,,,,,,,,,,,,                                    |
|,,,103,104,,,,,,,111,,,114,,,,,,,121,,,,,,,,,,131,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,157,,,,,162,,,,,,,169,,,,,174,,176,,,,,,,,,,,,,                              |
|,101,102,,104,,,,,,,,,113,114,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,130,131,,,,,,,,,,141,142,143,,,146,,,,150,,152,,,,,157,,,,,162,,,,,,,,,,,,174,,,,,,,,,,184,,,,,            |
|,,,,104,,,,,,,,,113,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,131,,,,,,,,,,141,142,143,,,146,,,,150,,,,,155,,157,,,,,162,,,,,,,169,,,,,174,,176,177,178,,,,,,,,,,,               |
|,,,,104,,,,,,,111,,,114,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,131,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,157,,,,,162,,,,,,,,,,,,174,,176,,,,,,,,,,,,,                                       |
|,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,                                                               |
|,,102,,104,,,,,,,,,113,114,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,130,131,,,,,,,,,,141,142,143,,,146,,,,150,,152,,,,,157,,,,,162,,,,,,,,,,,,174,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,                  |
|,,,,104,,,,,,,111,112,,114,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,131,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,157,,,,,162,,,,,,,169,,,,,174,,176,,,,,,,,,,,,,                                 |
|,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,                                                               |
|,,102,103,104,,,,,,,,,113,114,,,,,,,121,,,,,,,,,130,131,,,,,,,,,,141,142,143,,,146,,,,150,,152,,,,,157,,,160,,162,,,,,,,,,,,173,174,,176,,178,,,,,,,,,,,|
|,,,,104,,,,,,,111,,,114,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,131,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,157,,,,,162,,,,,,,,,,,,174,,176,,,,,,,,,,,,,                                       |
|,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,                                                               |
|,,,103,104,,,,,,,111,,,114,,,,,,,121,,,,,,,,,,131,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,157,,,,,162,,,,,,,169,,,,,174,,176,,,,,,,,,,,,,                              |
|,,,,104,,,,,,,111,,,114,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,131,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,157,,,,,162,,,,,,,169,,,,,174,,176,,,,,,,,,,,,,                                    |
|,,102,,104,,,,,,,,,113,114,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,130,131,,,,,,,,,,141,142,143,,,146,,,,150,,152,,,,,157,,,,,162,,,,,,,,,,,,174,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,                  |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


scala> df.select(trim(array_join(array_remove(split($"my_col", ","), ""),",")) as "my_col").show(false)
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|my_col                                                                             |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|104,111,114,131,157,162,169,174,176,                                               |
|104,111,114,131,157,162,169,174,176,                                               |
|104,111,114,131,157,162,169,174,176,                                               |
|104,111,114,131,157,160,162,174,176,                                               |
|104,111,114,131,157,162,169,174,176,                                               |
|104,111,131,157,160,162,169,174,176,                                               |
|103,104,111,114,121,131,157,162,169,174,176,                                       |
|101,102,104,113,114,130,131,141,142,143,146,150,152,157,162,174,184,               |
|104,113,131,141,142,143,146,150,155,157,162,169,174,176,177,178,                   |
|104,111,114,131,157,162,174,176,                                                   |
|                                                                                   |
|102,104,113,114,130,131,141,142,143,146,150,152,157,162,174,                       |
|104,111,112,114,131,157,162,169,174,176,                                           |
|                                                                                   |
|102,103,104,113,114,121,130,131,141,142,143,146,150,152,157,160,162,173,174,176,178|
|104,111,114,131,157,162,174,176,                                                   |
|                                                                                   |
|103,104,111,114,121,131,157,162,169,174,176,                                       |
|104,111,114,131,157,162,169,174,176,                                               |
|102,104,113,114,130,131,141,142,143,146,150,152,157,162,174,                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


scala> val myUdf = udf{(x:String) => if(x.endsWith(",")){x.dropRight(1)} else {x}}
myUdf: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,StringType,Some(List(StringType)))

scala> df.select(myUdf(trim(array_join(array_remove(split($"my_col", ","), ""),","))) as "my_col").show(false)
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|my_col                                                                             |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|104,111,114,131,157,162,169,174,176                                                |
|104,111,114,131,157,162,169,174,176                                                |
|104,111,114,131,157,162,169,174,176                                                |
|104,111,114,131,157,160,162,174,176                                                |
|104,111,114,131,157,162,169,174,176                                                |
|104,111,131,157,160,162,169,174,176                                                |
|103,104,111,114,121,131,157,162,169,174,176                                        |
|101,102,104,113,114,130,131,141,142,143,146,150,152,157,162,174,184                |
|104,113,131,141,142,143,146,150,155,157,162,169,174,176,177,178                    |
|104,111,114,131,157,162,174,176                                                    |
|                                                                                   |
|102,104,113,114,130,131,141,142,143,146,150,152,157,162,174                        |
|104,111,112,114,131,157,162,169,174,176                                            |
|                                                                                   |
|102,103,104,113,114,121,130,131,141,142,143,146,150,152,157,160,162,173,174,176,178|
|104,111,114,131,157,162,174,176                                                    |
|                                                                                   |
|103,104,111,114,121,131,157,162,169,174,176                                        |
|104,111,114,131,157,162,169,174,176                                                |
|102,104,113,114,130,131,141,142,143,146,150,152,157,162,174                        |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: thanks, will this work if input is `,,102,,,104` . Its not necessary to have a comma at start and end.

Answer (score 3):

You can use regexp_replace:

```scala
val df_cleaned = df.withColumn("cleaned", regexp_replace(col("my_col"), ",+", ","))
  .withColumn("cleaned", regexp_replace(col("cleaned"), "^,", ""))
  .withColumn("cleaned", regexp_replace(col("cleaned"), ",$", ""))
```

The first line removes all duplicate commas, the second and third line remove the leading and trailing commas.

Answer (score 0):

```scala
scala> df.select(trim(array_join(array_remove(split($"my_col", ","), ""),",")) as "my_col").show(false)
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|my_col                                                                             |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|104,111,114,131,157,162,169,174,176,                                               |
|104,111,114,131,157,162,169,174,176,                                               |
|104,111,114,131,157,162,169,174,176,                                               |
|104,111,114,131,157,160,162,174,176,                                               |
|104,111,114,131,157,162,169,174,176,                                               |
|104,111,131,157,160,162,169,174,176,                                               |
|103,104,111,114,121,131,157,162,169,174,176,                                       |
|101,102,104,113,114,130,131,141,142,143,146,150,152,157,162,174,184,               |
|104,113,131,141,142,143,146,150,155,157,162,169,174,176,177,178,                   |
|104,111,114,131,157,162,174,176,                                                   |
|                                                                                   |
|102,104,113,114,130,131,141,142,143,146,150,152,157,162,174,                       |
|104,111,112,114,131,157,162,169,174,176,                                           |
|                                                                                   |
|102,103,104,113,114,121,130,131,141,142,143,146,150,152,157,160,162,173,174,176,178|
|104,111,114,131,157,162,174,176,                                                   |
|                                                                                   |
|103,104,111,114,121,131,157,162,169,174,176,                                       |
|104,111,114,131,157,162,169,174,176,                                               |
|102,104,113,114,130,131,141,142,143,146,150,152,157,162,174,                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).